# Run the same function for 3 different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

There is a CS:GO crate spinning simulator that I am modifying to suit my own personal requirements, however I have hit a roadblock.

While I have been able to update and replace the images and probabilities, I can not achieve my next goal. Below is a link to the application: http://eg-graphics.com/zwooper/crates/index.html

Basically, you have to click which crate you want to open, and then you spin it.

What I would like is for there to be no crate selection, and for the user to just click "spin" and all 3 crates would spin at once and open...

The relevant code is located in `main.js` and the function is here:

```
 // Spin button click handler
$("#case-spin-btn").click(function(){
$('.error').hide().html('');

if ($('#password').val()!='') { 
    $.getJSON("/zwooper/crates/passwords.json", function(data) {

        if(data.success) {
            var passwords = data.passwords;

            for(let i in passwords) {
                if(passwords[i].password == $('#password').val() && passwords[i].timesToUse > 0) { 
                    $('.error').hide();
                    $('.passwordBlock').hide();
                    unboxCase();

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", "passwords.php?q="+passwords[i].password+"&item="+winningItem.getFullName(), true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        return;
                    },9500);

                };
            }
            $('.error').show().html('Password not found');
        }
    })
}
else {
    $('.error').show().html('Please enter password');
}

});
```

As you can see, if the password is inputted correctly it runs the function `unboxCase()`. I need this function to run 3 times, one for each of the 3 cases.

Password is "EGxo" without the quotes

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just talking out loud: It seems to pull a different list of passwords.json based on which case is selected. And clicking on a case triggers that somehow.

Comment: The passwords have nothing to do with the crate that is being opened, all the passwords are for is to spin and then log what prize was given to the player.

Comment: correct but this file http://eg-graphics.com/zwooper/crates/passwords.json seems to change with the click and successful submit. which may be a barrier to get them all to run at once. Still looking

Comment: just talking out loud again: currentCase must be set before unboxCase() is called. The default is csgocase1 (assault case). the other options are eSports2013 for the support case, and bravo for the specialist.